# SaaS / PaaS / IaaS / HaaS

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine

I've read:

- [IaaS, PaaS and SaaS Terms Clearly Explained and Defined](http://silverlighthack.com/post/2011/02/27/IaaS-PaaS-and-SaaS-Terms-Explained-and-Defined.aspx) and
- [Cloud Computing – Demystifying SaaS, PaaS and IaaS](http://www.cloudtweaks.com/2010/05/cloud-computing-demystifying-saas-paas-and-iaas/)

And I've got 2 questions:

1. Is Google App Engine considered PaaS or IaaS?
2. Is HaaS a subset of IaaS or is HaaS really just another name for IaaS?

Comment: Not sure about 1. As for 2: it is, ideologically, a subset - that is to say that in an IaaS I don't think it's necessary that the infrastructure elements treat the hardware as a _service_ per se (it could be proprietary OS/etc. dedicated for proprietary hardware). The differentiator is that the OS could belong in an IaaS but not in an HaaS.

Comment: @SnOrfus: Please post your answer as an answer so we can upvote it properly.

Comment: @S.Lott: It's only half of an answer at best, so I thought it left best as a comment. Will promote it.

Comment: @SnOrfus: Since it  doesn't ask for specific clarifications, it doesn't look like a comment.  Since it provides answers, it sure looks like an answer.

Comment: Both of your links are dead. Perhaps you could include a short summary of what you've gleaned from them or think is the main take-away from each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is from an article that I read "Toward a Unified Ontology of Cloud Computing"

1. As Google App Engine gives you a platform for better utilization of Google's resources, it can be considered PaaS. A good key for me is "Is this environment giving me some kind of API for better integration with a system? Then it's PaaS."
2. I read more than one definition about this, but nowadays what sounds better to me, and what the article writer says, is that HaaS, like CaaS (communication as a service) is a subset of IaaS: they create the infrastructure needed to perform IaaS, but it can't be considered essentially service like IaaS.

Here is a figure that describes what I'm saying:
[image: cloud layers]

Comment: By env, I suppose they mean environment.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about 1.

As for 2:

It is, ideologically, a subset. That is to say that in an IaaS I don't think it's necessary that the infrastructure elements treat the hardware as a service per se - it could be a proprietary OS/etc. dedicated for proprietary hardware.

The differentiator is that the OS could belong in an IaaS but not in an HaaS.

Comment: why do you call a Haas an Haas?

Comment: @Pacerier: When I'm saying it, I'm pronouncing it as individual letters as I don't consider it a word.

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine allows you to create our own application in Java, so it's a Platform As A Service. However, you only can use a restricted subset of Java, so it's actually closer to SaaS than to IaaS (which gives you a virtual machine and let you install whatever language stack or application you want).

Comment: Restrictions on what you can do don't really change the fact that it's PaaS. It's still a platform that you build your app on.

Comment: In fact, a PaaS is likely to have a few restrictions. After all, the whole point is that you get a platform that is abstracted from the actual facilities of the hardware/OS/software installed.